# Sending Email using SMTP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am trying to send email using smtp codeigniter. The code I am using is as below:

```
public function notify_marketing(){
    $config = Array(
                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'smtp_user' => 'myvalidemail@gmail.com', 
                    'smtp_pass' => '*******',//my valid email password
                    'mailtype' => 'html',
                    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                    'wordwrap' => TRUE
                  );

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");  
    $this->email->from('myvalidemail@gmail.com'); 
    $this->email->to('validreceiptent@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('My Subject');
    $this->email->message('Hello there');
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Email sent.");
    }
     else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

However I am getting the following error in the response. I tried other solutions from this site but didn't work.

```
    <div id="exception_error">
    <h1><span class="type">An Error Was Encountered [ 500 ]</span></h1>
    <div class="content">
        <p><p>220 smtp.googlemail.com ESMTP bv4sm16669443pbb.86 - gsmtp
<br /><pre>hello: 250-smtp.googlemail.com at your service, [110.44.127.179]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
</pre>lang:email_smtp_auth_pw<br />lang:email_send_failure_smtp<br /><pre>User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2015 12:03:42 +0545
From: <********@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <********@gmail.com>
To: *******@gmail.com
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?My_Subject?=
Reply-To: "********@gmail.com" <*********@gmail.com>
X-Sender: *******@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <55d2ce42747f5@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Code looks good, and config as well, but I had issues with gmail accounts themselves - check settings in gmail account, https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is perfect.

You need to use **Application password** of gmail not the gmail password. Please set a application password from gmail settings and give the password here.

It will work perfectly then. See More from [HERE](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Simple-Tricks-send-email-from-109912.S.5959285043661660163?trk=groups_search_item_list-0-b-ttl)

**Process to setting up a app password in gmail:**

1. Visit your [App passwords page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords). You may be asked to sign in to your Google Account.
2. At the bottom, click Select app and choose the app you’re using.
3. Click Select device and choose the device you’re using.
4. Select Generate.
5. Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.
6. Select Done.

Once you are finished, you’ll won’t see that App password code again. However, you will see a list of apps and devices you’ve created App passwords for.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot find setting to set application password.

Comment: @R.Karki I have included the process to get App Password.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Though I couldn't find the exact settings as you mentioned in above steps, however I turned on access for the  less secure apps on gmail setting and it worked. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Create a file named 'email.php' inside 'application/config' folder and add the below settings to it.

```
<?php
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //change this
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@gmail.com'; //change this
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password'; //change this
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
?>
```

In Controller:

```
<?php
//send mail
function sendmail()
{
    $this->load->library('email'); // load email library
    $this->email->from('user@gmail.com', 'sender name');
    $this->email->to('test1@gmail.com');
    $this->email->cc('test2@gmail.com'); 
    $this->email->subject('Your Subject');
    $this->email->message('Your Message');
    $this->email->attach('/path/to/file1.png'); // attach file
    $this->email->attach('/path/to/file2.pdf');
    if ($this->email->send())
        echo "Mail Sent!";
    else
        echo "There is error in sending mail!";
}
?>
```

Comment: To create a library should I put the file in `application/config` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The above code I presented worked fine after I turned on the access for less secure apps on gmail setting.